# Посимвольное чтение кириллической строки в PHP

Tags: php

Вот есть припусти такой код.

```
$str = 'Это строка';
echo $str[1];
```

Выведется какае-то ересь.Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы выводило нормальные символы.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

СТРОКА ЭТО НЕ МАССИВ. Нельзя просто так взять и обратиться к отдельному символу строки.

[image]

Используйте функции [explode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php) или [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

Например:

```
$str = 'hello';
$char_array = explode('', $str);
print $char_array[1]; //e
```

Comment: аххахаха. Спасибо, классный ответ. Только скажите почему на офф. сайте написано что к символу строки можно обращаться или через [], или {}?

Comment: Про "{}" вообще странно. Про "[]" я еще могу поверить, потому что php плохо знаю. Не могли бы Вы мне тыкнуть пальцем, где это на офф. сайте написано?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php
Заглавление String access and modification by character. Читайте дальше. А также там написано "Think of a string as an array of characters for this purpose." ахах)

Comment: о и правда можно через [] обращаться к символу. Не знал. Спасибо. 

Тогда у Вас проблема скорее всего в кодировке. Почитайте про iconv()или подобные функции.

Comment: Читал, что-то не получается.

Answer (score 5):

```
echo mb_substr($string, 0, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'hello';
$char_array = explode('', $str);
print $char_array[1]; //e
```

Не понимаю, как можно использовать это, когда с помощью `explode` можно разбить строку по словам на массив, но не слово по буквам. Разделитель должен быть в любом случае, хотя бы пробел, но он ни в коем случае не должен быть пустым.

Answer (score 0):

С поддержкой кириллицы:

```
$arChar = preg_split('/(?<!^)(?!$)/u', $string);
print_r($arChar);
```

Answer (score -1):

В PHP 5.5 такая конструкция посимвольного вывода `$str[1]` станет [**возможной**](http://rmcreative.ru/blog/post/chto-nas-zhdjot-v-php-5.5).

А пока,

```
$str = 'abc de';
$i = 0;
do {
    echo $str{$i} , '<br/>';
    ++$i;
} while (isset($str{$i}));
```

Возможны проблемы с выводом кириллических символов, как, впрочем, и с использованием `str_split`.

Так что, вариант, который предложил [[@KryDos](/users/10495/krydos)](/users/10495/krydos) выглядит предпочтительнее.

Comment: @Jeremen1:

- Если не ошибаюсь, то релиз 5.5
   состоится весной.
 - Большинство shared-хостингов (если,
   конечно, собираетесь на нём запускать
   проект) имеют поддержку PHP 5.2 - 5.3

Делайте выводы.

Да, можно использовать {}, если в строке отсутствуют кириллические символы.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так:

```
$str = 'Это строка';
echo mb_substr($str, 0, 1, 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// Получение первого символа строки
$str = 'This is a test.';
$first = $str[0];

// Получение третьего символа строки
$third = $str[2];
```

Comment: `$str = 'Это строка'; print($str[0]);` не работает.