# Обработка форм в php, как решить?

Tags: php

1. Создайте форму с method=”post”.
2. В форме должны быть текстовая область (textarea) и кнопка.
3. В обработчике необходимо принять строку из текстовой области.
4. Создайте массив, где каждый элемент будет содержать 1 символ из переданной строки.
5. Удалите каждый чётный элемент (то есть 0, 2, 4 и так далее).
6. Соедините все элементы получившегося массива в одну строку и выведите её.

Примечание: Должно получиться что-то наподобие этого: пришла строка «Моя строка», а выйти в браузер должно: «о тоа».

```html
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
    <textarea name="text" value="<?=$text?>"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить" />
</form>
```

```php
$text = false;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $text = htmlspecialchars($_POST['text']);

      for($i = 0; $i <strlen($text); $i++){

    $arr[] = $i;
    }
    echo $arr;
}
```

```html
//4. Создайте массив, где каждый элемент будет содержать 1 символ из переданной строки.
Если каждой строки textarea, то так может

<form method="post" action=""> 
    <textarea name='text'></textarea>
    <input type='submit' name="Enter">
</form>
```

```php
if(isset($_POST['Enter'])){
    $text = preg_split("~\n~",trim($_POST['text']));
    print_r(
      array_combine(array_keys($text), array_values(preg_replace("~.{1}\\K.+~","",$text)))
    );
}
```

```php
//п.5 Удалите каждый чётный элемент (то есть 0, 2, 4 и так далее)
$text ='abcd'; //переданный текст
for ($i=0; $i < mb_strlen($text,'utf-8'); $i++) {
    if ($i % 2 == 0) {
        $text{$i} = '';
    }
}

//echo $text;
echo mb_strlen($text, 'utf-8');
```

Comment: и проблема то в чем? задачу мы увидели, попытка решения вроде тоже есть, а загвоздка то в чем, мы догадаться должны?

Comment: @teran всё вместе это не работает. должна вывестись  «Моя строка», а выйти в браузер : «о тоа». - но ничего не выводит в итоге

Comment: ну дак вы можете привести один нормальный фрагмент кода, а не несколько конкурирующих отрывков?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так решил это задание, не идеальное, однако кириллицу обрабатывает корректно

```
<?php
$enterText = null;                                      // Создаем переменную
// Вывод текста ошибки
$failureEnterText = 'echo: Введите текст, допустимы цифры, без спецсимволов; <b>Пример:</b> <i>Моя строка;</i>';
        
if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'POST') {      // Проверка метода отправки данных
  if (isset($_POST['sendEnterText'])) {                 // Проверка нажатия кнопки формы 'Отправить'
    if (isset($_POST['enterText'])) {                   // Проверка заполения textarea

      // Удадение спецсивлов
      $enterText = preg_replace('/[^ A-za-zА-яа-яЁё\d]/ui', '', $_POST['enterText']);       
                    
      if (empty($enterText) == false) {                 // Проверка на пустопу
                        
        // Разбор строки по регулярному выражению, во избежание ���
        $splitString = preg_split('/(?<!^)(?!$)/u', $enterText);                            
                            
        echo "echo: Вы ввели '$enterText' => ";
                        
        // Посимвольное сохранение в массив, и вывод массива, для отображения результата
        foreach ($splitString as $textCharacters) $textCharactersArray[] = $textCharacters;
        echo '[' . implode(', ', $textCharactersArray) . '];<br>';
                        
        // Посимвольное сохранение нечетных элементов по ключу в массив, и вывод массива
        foreach ($textCharactersArray as $key => $textCharacters) {
          if ($key % 2 == 1) $textArraySelectedCharacters[] = $textCharacters;
        }
        echo 'echo: ' . implode('', $textArraySelectedCharacters) . ';<br>';
                    
      } else {
        echo "echo: Вы ввели => '{$enterText}';<br>";    // Вывод введенных данных
        $failureEnterText;                               // Вывод ошибки в случае пустоты
      }
                    
    } else {$failureEnterText;}     // Вывод ошибки в случае незаполения textarea
  } else {$failureEnterText;}       // Вывод ошибки в случае не нажатия кнопки
} else {$failureEnterText;}         // Вывод ошибки в случае отправки данных не методои 'POST'
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" method="post">
  <textarea type="text" name="enterText" rows="2" placeholder="Введите текст"></textarea><br>
  <button type="submit" name="sendEnterText">Отправить</button>
</form>
<small><?php if (isset($textArraySelectedCharacters)) {echo echo 'echo: ' . implode('', $textArraySelectedCharacters) . ';';} else {echo $failureEnterText;}?></small>
```

В случае ввода пустых данных получаем такой ответ `echo: Вы ввели => '';`

И ошибку `echo: Введите текст, допустимы цифры, без спецсимволов; Пример: Моя строка;`

Если введем 'Моя строка' `echo: Вы ввели 'Моя строка' => [М, о, я, , с, т, р, о, к, а];`

Результат выполнения `echo: о тоа;`

Регулярное выражение по удалению спецсимволов

`preg_replace('/[^ A-za-zА-яа-яЁё\d]/ui', '', $text);` взял [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/815621/390783)

Регулярное выражение по разбору строки с 'кириллицей', во избежание ���

`preg_split('/(?<!^)(?!$)/u', $enterText);` взял [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/669229/390783)

Answer (score 0):

взять строку

```
$txt   = "abcdefgh klmnopqrst"; // $_POST['text'];
```

разбить на символы

```
$chars = preg_split("//u", $txt,-1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

оставить нечетные

```
$odd   = array_filter($chars, function($idx){ return $idx & 1;}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

слить обратно

```
$result = implode("", $odd);
```

но это решение скорее всего у вас не примут, потому что это учебное задание, и потребует написания циклов и посимвольному перебору строки.

---

в целом четные буквы можно еще удалить, например, так

```
$result = preg_replace("/.(.)/", "$1", $txt);
```

Comment: даже если такой вариант, то выводит �������� т.е.  не по заданию в конце '-о тоа', если написать 'моя строка' в txt. здесь ещё проблема с кодировкой- пробовал `mb_strlen($text, 'utf-8');` - не меняет.  но, наверное, нужно все же по пунктам и вначале сделать форму и т.д.

Comment: @ruben убедитесь, что у вас сам пхп файл сохранен в утф, а так же, что в мета-тэгах страницы указана кодировка утф

Comment: вот пробую менять в редакторе на 'utf-8', и мета-тэги поставил ` <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`  - что-то не так(

Comment: @ruben регулярное выражение на `//u` замените

Comment: а вот такой вариант если? `$t = false;
$text = implode('', array_filter(preg_split('//u', $_POST['text']), function($l) use(&$t) { return ($t = !$t); }));`