# Странные символы при выводе массива поэлементно

Tags: php7

Обнаружил странное поведение при выводе массива поэлементно. Если вкратце, есть программа, допустим, такая:

```
<?php
    echo "<html> \n <head> \n <title> \n";
    echo "Вывод переменной";
    echo "</title> \n <meta charset = \"utf-8\">";
    echo "</head> \n <body> \n";
        $var = "qwsdft5ый";
    echo "Выведем переменную в целом. </br>";
    echo "Переменная - $var - девять символов: шесть латинских, цифра, два русских </br>";
    echo "Количество символов в переменной - ".mb_strlen ($var)."</br>";
    echo "Теперь выведем переменную поэлементно, так как переменная - это стринг, массив:</br>";
        for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen ($var); $i++)
          echo $var[$i]." ";
    echo '</br>';
    echo "</body> \n </html> \n";
?>
```

При её запуске в браузере она выдаёт следующее:

Выведем переменную в целом.
Переменная - qwsdft5ый - девять символов: шесть латинских, цифра, два русских
Количество символов в переменной - 9
Теперь выведем переменную поэлементно, так как переменная - это стринг, массив:
q w s d f t 5 � �

Что это за символы в конце? 
Спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Посимвольное чтение кириллической строки в PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/186289/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php)

Comment: @RifmaMan принятый ответ там шляпа какая, то а соседний то что надо. в частности, индексированный доступ к элементам строки равносилен вызову `substr`, это вроде в документации даже было отражено.

Comment: @teran принятый — шляпа, ктож спорит, но вопрос уже задавался и он решен!

Comment: @RifmaMan я скорее для топикстартера отметил. что принятый там ответ шляпный, а не для вас :)

Comment: @teran - равносильность относительная - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c4580158560352194488901c64511aff78cf4d58

Comment: @splash58 чего вы хотите продемострировать? я пишу, что `[] = substr`, а вы вызываете `mb_substr`.

Comment: что значит "продемонстрировать"? я хочу сказать, что фраза "индексированный доступ к элементам строки равносилен вызову substr", вероятно, не верна. Если включена перегрузка строковых функций, то в код, на который я ссылаюсь, можно подставить  substr

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что кириллица хранится в двухбайтовой кодировке, а латиница и цифры в однобайтовой. Так что при обращении к элементу он режется до 1 байта.

Можно использовать `mb_substr` как раз для многобайтовых кодировок.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen ($var); $i++)
          echo mb_substr($var, $i,1)." ";
```